# PHP Page Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I've coded a form for a hiring application on an online game, but am running some issues when I actually put the code on the website. Running this on my local apache web server runs fine, but doing this on a LiteSpeed web server online seems to not work. Is there anything invalid in the code?

I've set the code already to detect any errors (I've removed that from the below sample), but nothing turns up except for undefined variables (which is fine in this case).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Zone Application Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require("includes.php");
  function displayElements($category) {
    echo "<div id=\"left\">\n";
    $col1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gp_applications WHERE category = '$category' ORDER BY id ASC");
    echo "<h3>" . $category . "</h3>\n";
    echo "<form action=\"#\" method=\"get\">\n";
    echo "<select name=\"category\">\n";
    if ($category=="Unread Apps") {
      echo "<option value=\"Unread Apps\" selected=\"selected\">Unread Apps</option>\n";
      echo "<option value=\"Deleted Apps\">Deleted Apps</option>\n";
      echo "<option value=\"Good Apps\">Good Apps</option>\n";
    }
    if ($category=="Deleted Apps") {
      echo "<option value=\"Unread Apps\">Unread Apps</option>\n";
      echo "<option value=\"Deleted Apps\" selected=\"selected\">Deleted Apps</option>\n";
      echo "<option value=\"Good Apps\">Good Apps</option>\n";
    }
    if ($category=="Good Apps") {
      echo "<option value=\"Unread Apps\">Unread Apps</option>\n";
      echo "<option value=\"Deleted Apps\">Deleted Apps</option>\n";
      echo "<option value=\"Good Apps\" selected=\"selected\">Good Apps</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Choose\">\n";
    echo "</form>\n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<form action=\"#\" method=\"get\">\n";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"category\" value=\"" . $category . "\">\n";
    echo "<select name=\"id\" size=\"25\">\n";
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($col1)) {
      echo "<option value=\"" . $row1[id] . "\">" . $row1[q2] . "</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"read\" value=\"Read Application\">\n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete Application\">\n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"unread\" value=\"Mark Application Unread\">\n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"good\" value=\"Good Application\">\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<form action=\"#\" method=\"get\">\n";
    echo "<div id=\"bottom\">\n";
    echo "<select name=\"appMode\">";
    $mode = file_get_contents('mode.txt');
    if($mode=="yes") {
    echo "<option value=\"appon\" selected=\"selected\">Turn Application On</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"appoff\">Turn Application Off</option>";
    } else {
    echo "<option value=\"appon\">Turn Application On</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"appoff\" selected=\"selected\">Turn Application Off</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"appModeBtn\" value=\"Toggle App Mode\">";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</form>";
  }
  function executeAppAction($id) {
  if (isset($_GET['good'])) {
      mysql_query("UPDATE gp_applications SET category='Good Apps' WHERE id='$id'")or die(mysql_error());
      header("Location: admin.php?action=admin");
    }
  if (isset($_GET['unread'])) {
      mysql_query("UPDATE gp_applications SET category='Unread Apps' WHERE id='$id'")or die(mysql_error());
      header("Location: admin.php");
    }
    if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
      mysql_query("UPDATE gp_applications SET category='Deleted Apps' WHERE id='$id'")or die(mysql_error());
      header("Location: admin.php");
    }
    if (isset($_GET['read'])) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gp_applications WHERE id='$id'");
    if ($result) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
    echo "<div id=\"formBody\">";
    //application opener, not needed to view
    echo "</div>\n";
  }
  }
    if($_POST['pwd'] || isset($_COOKIE['zonegp_application_login'])) {
      if($_POST['pwd']=="xxxx") {
        $hour = time() + 3600;
        $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
        setcookie('zonegp_application_login', $pwd, $hour);
      }
      if($_COOKIE['zonegp_application_login']=="xxxx" || $_POST['pwd']=="xxxx") {
        echo "<h1>The Doctor's Application Manager</h1>\n";
        echo "<p><a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a></p>\n";
        if($_GET['category']) {
        $appcategory = $_GET['category'];
        }
        if(empty($appcategory)) {
          $appcategory = "Unread Apps";
          displayElements($appcategory);
        }
        else {
          displayElements($appcategory);
        }
        if($_GET['id']) {
          $id = $_GET['id'];
          executeAppAction($id);
        }
        if ($_GET['appModeBtn']) {
          if($_GET['appMode']=="appon") {
            $myFile = "mode.txt";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            $stringData = "yes";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            fclose($fh);
            header("Location: admin.php");
          }
          if($_GET['appMode']=="appoff") {      
            $myFile = "mode.txt";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            $stringData = "no";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            fclose($fh);
            header("Location: admin.php");
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        echo "Incorrect Password";
      }
    }
    else {
      header("Location: login.html");
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hosted Locally: [image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63673315/sopic1.png]

Hosted Online: [image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63673315/sopic2.png]

Yes, I am running PHP on the website version.

Comment: Are you *sure* there are no errors? If the error happened within the <select> element, then you'd have to do View Source to see it (or check the error log). Have you verified that the database connection is being made successfully?

Comment: Most probably `require("includes.php");` : includes.php is missing from server. See your CSS is loading and its only at require does it stop. If its there then look for errors in that file

Comment: I see no errors in the require includes file because the file is there and also it works when I actually submit an application with the same includes file.

Answer (score 1):

please add

```
var_dump(file_exists('includes.php'));
```

just before

```
require('includes.php');
```

require drops any further code if the file is not found

Comment: Thank you for the advise, although this does not pertain to the answer. Is there any error in my code I should be worried about that may cause this particular server to act up?

Comment: Ah, I think I found the problem. The source says that the body is not going into the code, which means it has to do something with me opening the PHP tags into the HTML. I'll test it out.

Comment: The error had to do with the cookie not functioning. It's not adding into the browser when I submit the code. This must be some odd restriction due to the hosting company I am using. I know this because the page submits, but when I try any further action, it takes me to that blank page. Thanks for your help!